# How do I disable zoom effect when hovering mouse over thumbnails in Google Image Search?

Tags: google-image-search, customization, thumbnail

I think this is something of a usability flaw, so I wonder if it's possible to disable the effect that scales thumbnails up when mousing over the results.

Either via a setting somewhere in my Google account, in my browser settings (Chrome), or via 3rd part browser (preferably Chrome) extensions.

#### Bonus

Bonus point if there's a solution (presumably extension) that allows for **optional** thumbnail zooming via keyboard hotkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Remove Image Search Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-image-search-zoom/lkfebdepfhbfbkkifenolihnmieiicem) Extension.

Full Disclosure: I wrote this after reading your post.

Comment: No hotkey yet. It just disables the zoom.

Comment: Thanks! However it doesn't affect the zooming for me. (Chrome 23.0.1271.95, OS X 10.8.2). I guess support discussions for this might be better off somewhere else, but, well :)

Comment: I tested with Chrome 23.0.1271.95 on XP and 7. It's written in Javascript and CSS.